# is there a way to create an empty anki deck using python?

Tags: python, anki

i'm trying to create an Anki addon, and part of it requires creating an empty anki deck, and then importing a textfile into it, i've looked it up and i can't seem to find a clear answer on how to do it programmatically , any help will be great! thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this Python3 project that looks interesting:

https://github.com/kerrickstaley/genanki

I'm going to use this to help me study for interviews. ;-)